# Jquery repeating clicks when resizing

Tags: jquery, resize

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdEp4/6/)

When I resize the window, the blue block is changing his size.
If I click on blue block, I add symbol * to it.
But if I click on the blue block, resize window, and again click on resized block, instead of one *, will add a lot of symbols *.

What's the problem? I need add one symbol *, after I resize the window.

```
function c_click() {
    $('.blue-block').click(function(){
        $('.blue-block').append('<div>*</div>')
    });
}


$(window).ready(function(){
    c_click();
})

$(window).resize(function(){
    c_click();
})
```

Comment: Well, you are adding a new event handler whenever the `resize` event fires. Why are you calling `c_click` on `resize` if that's not what you want?

Comment: @FelixKling, Thanks. The problem is solved. I got confused. It was my mistake. In jsfiddle was simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery allows for multiple event handlers attached to one element. In this case, each time `resize()` is evoked, you register a `click` handler, which results in the multiple '*'